# Handling large values in C# REDIS clients

Tags: stackexchange.redis

I am developing a component that will provide a GET REST endpoint that will return a large (up to 2MB) JSON array of data. I will be using REDIS to cache the JSON array and the REST endpoint is implemented using a Web API 2 project.

I assumed that I could just return the data in the `Response` `Stream` so that I don't have to have very large strings in memory, but when I took a look at StackExchange.Redis I couldn't find any methods that return a `Stream`.

It appears that https://github.com/ctstone/csredis does, but this project looks pretty static now.

Am I missing something, or is there a workaround for this?